# z-index solution for IE7

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem with `z-index` in IE7.

My actual requirement is to open the pop (kind of) div when you click on the heading.

So I am using position:absolute to pop div to place it accordingly. It works absolutely fine in all the browsers except IE7.

In IE7 you can see that second heading text is coming over pop div.

**Here is my CSS**

```
.heading{
  border:solid 1px #d6d6d6;
  background:#efefef;
  padding:2px 6px;  
  margin-bottom:6px;
}
a{
  color:#088f93;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;  
}
.pop-div{
  position:relative;
}
.pop-up{
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:0;
  background:#fff;
  padding:8px;
  border: 1px solid #c6d0d9;
  color:#404040;
  display:none;
  z-index:10000
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/kugomoqe/8/)**

Comment: Removing `position: relative` from the `.pop-div` elements and using `margin-left` and `margin-top` instead of `left` and `top` to `.pop-up` should work.

Comment: position:relative is given to place the absolute div. And your suggetion gives oputput like this [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/kugomoqe/15#)... It is not taking margin left

Comment: I think you should consider writing conditional css..